# What comes next in this poetic sequence?

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> This is an ode to me 
>   I am just too good
>   When compared to thee.
>   For I am indeed so hot
>   My fire cannot be contained
>   Near me, sit you shall not.
>   Sever your self-worth
>   And behold my might
>   So we may dine on earth.

This is not your average sequence. What comes next? why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A suggestion for the next line

> I am better than all men.

It seems as though

> Every line contains a word which is one letter different (either by replacement or subtraction) from the corresponding number of the line. 
>  This is an ode (**one**) to me 
>  I am just too (**two**) good 
>  When compared to thee (**three**) 
>  For (**Four**) I am indeed so hot 
>  My fire (**five**) cannot be contained 
>  Near me, sit (**six**) you shall not. 
>  Sever (**Seven**) your self-worth 
>  And behold my might (**eight**) 
>  So we may dine (**nine**) on earth.

Comment: This is exactly the reasoning I was going for. I was just expecting the number for the answer, but you went a step further. Take your checkmark!

Comment: Thank you. It's a great puzzle. I considered writing a stanza but couldn't come up with anything corresponding to twelve.

Comment: @hexomino - Did your next line involve the word "elven"?  It's the only one I can think of...

Comment: Suggestion for hexomino to complete the stanza: >! He who dozes (**dozen**) will be lost

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman - Haha, yeah.

Comment: There's also this [beaut of a word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevon)

Comment: @Will, I like that.

Comment: @Will - Though it would be very tricky to get that word into a poem.

Comment: Dwelve not too long on it